# Cassandra: Writes after setting a column to null are lost randomly. Is this a bug, or I am doing something wrong?

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax

```
@Test
public void testWriteUpdateRead() throws Exception {
  Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder()
      .addContactPoint("127.0.0.1")
      .build();
  Session cs = cluster.connect();
  cs.execute("DROP KEYSPACE if exists readtest;");
  cs.execute("CREATE KEYSPACE readtest WITH replication " +
      "= {'class':'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor':1};");
  cs.execute("create table readtest.sessions(" +
      "id text primary key," +
      "passwordHash text," +
      ");");

  for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    String sessionID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    cs.execute("insert into readtest.sessions (id, passwordHash) values('" + sessionID + "', null)");
    cs.execute("update readtest.sessions set passwordHash='" + sessionID + "' where id = '" + sessionID + "' ");
    ResultSet rs = cs.execute("select * from readtest.sessions where id = '" + sessionID + "'");
    Row row = rs.one();
    assertThat("failed ith time=" + i, row.getString("passwordHash"), equalTo(sessionID));
  }
  cs.close();
  cluster.close();
}
```

The above test always fails, and always on some random iteration. Can anyone explain why sometimes the update is lost?

I am running Cassandra locally, single node. Installed using brew on osx.

---

**Stack Trace:**

```
java.lang.AssertionError: failed ith time=4
Expected: "fd2fb850-b3ad-4bfb-8971-485c4df097dc"
     but: was null
    at org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat(MatcherAssert.java:20)
    at in.folks.blaze.service.CassandraTest.testWriteUpdateRead(CassandraTest.java:41)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:211)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

---

Other info:

```
Cassandra version: [cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 2.1.2 | CQL spec 3.2.0 | Native protocol v3]
java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
  <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
  <artifactId>cassandra-driver-mapping</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.12</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
  <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
  <version>1.10.17</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
  <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
  <version>1.3</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this.

Comment: with exact same configuration on osx? same versions etc.?

Comment: Different java (doubt that's the issue). Same CQL driver version. I'm on `2.1.2-SNAPSHOT`, let me try to pull.

Comment: Nope, not seeing the error at all.

Comment: Are you running tests in parallel?

Comment: nope, only one test. what os are you using? and what java version?

Comment: Mac with build 1.8.0_20-b26.

Comment: this is strange, how are you installing cassandra? brew? source?

Comment: I have the source. Built and ran.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be an issue where a row is updated right after it's created.  If you were to wait a small period of time after the second update, you would get the correct value, that does seem to be an issue, but perhaps only noticeable when running cassandra locally.

I suspect this is a cassandra issue, though it seems to be currently resolved on trunk and cassandra-2.1 branches.  I can reproduce against 1.2.19, 2.0.11, and 2.1.2, but I cannot reproduce against trunk or cassandra-2.1.  I can't seem to pinpoint the exact change based on the changelog.

EDIT Jan 5 2014:  A comment on the user list has more explanation for what is likely to be happening:  https://groups.google.com/a/lists.datastax.com/forum/#!topic/java-driver-user/0IDCz96lAeA.  Apparently this happens when the timestamps of the writes are exactly the same.

Comment: Did you create a Jira perchance?

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, I meant to open up an issue after doing some more testing but I forgot over new years :).  Wanted to do a little more testing, I could only reproduce using OS X.  When running on Ubuntu 14.04 the issue was not reproducible for me with 2.0.11, 2.1.2, cassandra-2.0 or cassandra-2.1.  [CASSANDRA-8555](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-8555)